# How to have an abstract class require an interface to be implemented by descendant classes?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

I want to make an abstract class that imposes a restriction that its child classes must implement an interface. I want to avoid having to implement the interface class in the abstract class. The code below won't do what I'd like. Does anyone have a suggestion of what I could do?

```
public interface IItem()
{
     bool IsUsable();
}

public abstract class Item : IItem
{
    MemberVar var;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class Something : Item
{
     public bool IsUsable()
     {
         return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just make the method `abstract` in your abstract class :

```
public abstract class Item : IItem
{
    //...

    public abstract bool IsUsable();
}
```

In the classes that inherit the `Item` class use the `override` keyword :

```
public override bool IsUsable()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

The overriding implementations stubs can be automatically added by VS by right-clicking on the parent abstract class and selecting `Implement Abstract Class` :

[image]

Comment: the descendant method has to use
    public override bool IsUsable(){}

I tried to edit the question and still believe it should be edited as this answer does not fully give code for the true answer.

Answer (score 0):

implement the interface in the base class with abstract methods and/or properties

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `abstract` keyword to every method/properties that the interface requires to implement.

For instance, this is how the `DoSomething()` method should look:

```
public abstract void DoSomething();
```

This way the derived classes will have to implement the interface themselves.